# Google Drive Image hotlinking

Tags: images, google-drive

Does Google Drive allows to hotlink the images? For example, I can upload images there and link to them on my website? Will it violate their terms and condition?

Comment: You could read the terms and conditions maybe? However why would you host images on Google Drive?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that this will not violate the terms of service. However, this is what Picasa Web Albums is for.

Comment: *How* do you do it? I need to insert these images into a Google Sheets sheet. My question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86081/insert-image-from-google-drive-into-google-sheets

Answer (score 7):

You can do it and it will not violate the terms and conditions at all.

Just make sure that the "Share Options" of the image is "Anyone who has a link" and "Does not require sign-in".

It will be a violation only if you do not have copyright of the particular image(s) in question.