# Sum values across multiple Sheets IDs automatically by creating a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I used this post to have all Google Sheets IDs in a folder
[Getting all files' file-id from a folder in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86846/getting-all-files-file-id-from-a-folder-in-google-drive)

I would like to make a formula or script to sum values in table across all these sheets IDs (note, the table is present in all sheets with same cell range).

Instead of copying and pasting the sheets Ids manually every time, I would like to make formula with variables that represents sheets ID so that every time I just past the sheets ID and the variables are assigned for each sheets.

Some thing in my mind like this:

```
a=1bsKy3bx9x2sYbM4BBvUjaYDdtveL1XV1l8wp8-CUD1c

b= 1fUb8H44PpeZpu40mfzK1_vuNEoLAyhiHjNcSOGTfLJU

c=1CckyrVFklIdQZa6PCM6mByvV9UK14zEwnoaK0PueTHg
```

And so on... while the formula is fixed

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Are you familiar with/have you experimented with `importrange`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHxPe6OhdXbsKWDPUA92mXXw4A2RMiUcOq6Ux5XaXCw/edit#gid=0

Comment: '''=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("1CckyrVFklIdQZa6PCM6mByvV9UK14zEwnoaK0PueTHg", "'statistics'!d6"),
     IMPORTRANGE("1bsKy3bx9x2sYbM4BBvUjaYDdtveL1XV1l8wp8-CUD1c", "'statistics'!d6"))
'''
But i need to copy paste this formula in every cell to count and change the cell range as well.. Also I need to copy the sheet ID every time I need to which is a long process>> my project is having a specific sheet ID for every day in a month.. so monthly I'm counting /sum all 30 sheets Ids in this way.. so i have to repeat for every month.. definitely there is a way but I'm still looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following set-up

In cell `C2` place `="'statistics'!d6"` and so on

Then in cell `D2` the below formula and drag it down

```
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE($B$2, C2),IMPORTRANGE($B$4, C2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats awsome... Thanks.. you save my life> I could add lot of ranges and sheets ID